# Week day name incremental in Shell scripting?

Tags: shell

I'm new in shell scripting and am looking to like this output

```
 1 | 1 | odd | Monday
 1 | 2 | even |Tuesday
  "
  "
 1 | 7 | odd | Sunday
 2 | 1 | odd | Monday
 2 | 2 | even| Tuesday
  "
  "
 2 | 7 | odd | Sunday
 3 | 1 | odd | Monday
 3 | 2 | even| Tuesday
  "
  " 
 3 | 7 | odd | Sunday
```

I tried below script

```
 i=1
 j=1
 while [ $i -le 3 ] 
 do
      for (( j=1; j<=7; j++ ))
      do      
            if [ $(($j%2)) -eq 0 ];
            then    
                    echo  "$i | $j | even "
            else    
                    echo  "$i | $j | odd"
            fi
      done
  ((i++)) 
 done
```

am getting like this Output

```
 1 | 1 | odd 
 1 | 2 | even
  "
  "
 1 | 7 | odd 
 2 | 1 | odd 
 2 | 2 | even
  "
  "
 2 | 7 | odd 
 3 | 1 | odd 
 3 | 2 | even
  "
  " 
 3 | 7 | odd
```

Please help me  "Week Day Name incremental in fourth column" where can i add the week name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date utility can display day of week, so you just need to tell her right date. Here is solution which does it with offset relatively to the actual date.

```
 dow=`date +%u`
 i=1
 j=1
 while [ $i -le 3 ] 
 do
      for (( j=1; j<=7; j++ ))
      do
            offset=$(( $j - $dow ))
            dow_str=`date --date="$offset days" +%A`
            if [ $(($j%2)) -eq 0 ];
            then
                    echo  "$i | $j | even | $dow_str"
            else
                    echo  "$i | $j | odd | $dow_str"
            fi
      done
  ((i++))
 done
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.... but i have a small doubt could please explain me...offset=$(( $j - $dow ))
            dow_str=`date --date="$offset days" +%A`  what's gng on there

Comment: day +%A would display actual day of week. With --date parameter you can change actual date for some other date. So we have to count the offset from actual date to date we want.

Comment: Perhaps simpler solution is the one of @Rakholiya Jenish

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using array. Store all the days in an array as:

```
declare -a week=('Sunday' 'Monday' 'Tuesday' 'Wednesday' 'Thursday' 'Friday' 'Saturday');
```

and then to access it, do it in for loop with the key as `j mod 7`. This will give you the week day name starting from Monday.